# Conditional Formatting cells based on how many times it appears in separate Column

Tags: google-sheets, countif, gs-conditional-formatting

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12TsEEj3LQSIOv2m6LRRS6FCLvIkuUo_ECfQvK4gw4d8/edit?usp=sharing

I want to use conditional formatting to count the amount of times a name appears in Column H and make the corresponding name in Column B red if it shows up once and crossed out if it shows up twice.

How can I do this? I used COUNTIF but I don't know how to attach the formatting to a specific name/string in Column B so it just formats the next one on the list (I think).

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear any conditional formatting from ColumnB, select B3 to the end of your range to format and Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... `Custom formula is` and

```
=countif(H:H,B3)=2
```

with strikethrough. Add another rule (same range) with `Custom formula is` and

```
=countif(H:H,B3)=1
```

with red fill and <kbd>Done</kbd>.